# embeber dll's o referencias en mi programa con visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Hola estaba intentando que automaticamente las dll's que requieren mi programa sean añadidas por medio de alguna extensión o algo. Probe con costura.fuddy pero me da el error:

```
coustura.fuddy no debug symbols
```

Al ver que no funcionaba intente con resource.embedder pero daba algunos errores tipo:

```
La variable 'exception1' se ha declarado pero nunca se usa
```

Al final igualmente me pide las librerías por lo que tampoco funciono. Alguna idea como podría hacer para que las dll o referencias se incluyan cuando compile mi proyecto??

Estaba intentando embeber la librería MetroFramework . Se que existe Ilmergue pero queria hacerlo compilandolo o de alguna manera mas simple.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar de esta manera:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\dll", "*.dll"); // Trae todos los ensamblados de esa carpeta
foreach (string file in files)
{
  Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file); // cargas cada ensamblado.
}
```

Saludos